# Brackets and omitted argument in a function

Tags: spacing

Sometimes, it is useful in math notations to write $u(x,\cdot)$ where the second argument of the function u is intentionally omitted. However, the above instruction generates a fairly questionable spacing between `\cdot` and `)`. For instance, $u(L,\cdot\,)$ is slightly nicer. What is the right way to code the above function in LateX?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest first of all to make a specific command for it, so you don't forget what spacing you have decided for.

I show several possible definitions, choose the one you prefer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\blank}{{{}\cdot{}}}

\begin{document}

$u(x,\cdot)$

$u(x,\cdot\,)$

$u(x,\blank)$

\renewcommand{\blank}{{\mspace{1mu}\cdot\mspace{1mu}}}

$u(x,\blank)$

\renewcommand{\blank}{{\mspace{2mu}\cdot\mspace{2mu}}}

$u(x,\blank)$

\renewcommand{\blank}{{-}}

$u(x,\blank)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The last redefinition shows how you can comply with a fussy coauthor who doesn't like the dot and prefers a dash. Using a personal command makes the change very easy.

Some explanations. Since `\cdot` is a binary operation symbol, if TeX finds it immediately before or after punctuation or immediately before or after a delimiter (in your case two conditions apply), it considers it an ordinary symbol. Thus you get

```
,<thin space><dot>)
```

Adding `\,` will make

```
,<thin space><dot><thin space>)
```

On the other hand, if you have `u(\cdot,y)`, you get

```
(<dot>,
```

with no spacing at all. The definition with `{{}\cdot{}}` will consider `\cdot` as a binary operation, with empty operands, so we get

```
,<thin space><med space><dot><med space>)
```

Using `{\mspace{1mu}\cdot\mspace{1mu}}` the dot is considered as ordinary, because it has no operands on either side. So you get

```
,<thin space><1mu><dot><1mu>)
```

and

```
(<1mu><dot><1mu>,
```

in the first variable case. The asymmetry is desired.